# Creating wav file from RIFF string

Tags: c#, wav

I am creating a Voice Authentication system, for that I am using third party API which stores my wav file and when I call GET, it returns the RIFF format encoded string in response.

I am not able to figure out a way to convert this RIFF into a wav file.

I tried below code, it is creating wav file but the wav is currupted:

```
using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(""))
                {

                    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\wavFile.wav", FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseData);
                        writer.Write(data);
                    }
                }
```

I tried ASCII along with UTF8 but same result. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am calling third-party API and they have sent only RIFF big string in response which starts with "RIFFfZ WAVEfmt", I am not able to figure out how to decode this and convert it into wav file @ThomasWeller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not read the response as a `string`. A wave file is binary data which may contain byte sequences which are not valid for strings.

The [WebClient (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) can directly [download binary data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f(v=vs.110).aspx) without need of converting it.

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] wave = webClient.DownloadData("...");
}
```

Comment: Bang on :) You are correct :) That was the issue. Thanks